# ERROR TypeError: this.dateDebut.getTime is not a function : Angular5

Tags: angular, angular5, frontend

I'm working with angular5 , i have two input with type date .
I'm trying to not validate a form if the first date input is greater than the second date input .

So there is two cases :

1. When dateOne>dateTwo an error message appears to the user .
2. When dateOne
   the user can submit the form .

Here is the code i tried to do :

This is .html file :

```
    <div class="modal-body">
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="addProjecToClients()">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label">Choisir un client : </label>


          <div class="col-sm-6">

            <ng-select  *ngIf="_listClients"
                         [items]="_listClients"
                          bindLabel ="nom"
                          bindValue ="id"
                        [(ngModel)]="selectedPersonId"
                        formControlName="selectedPersonId"
                         >
            </ng-select>

          </div>
        </div>

        <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label">Information liées au contrat : </label>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label" >Date one :  </label>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="date" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                   placeholder=".form-control-sm"  [(ngModel)]="dateOne"
formControlName="dateOne">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label" for="input-small">Date two : </label>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="date" id="input-small" name="input-small" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                   placeholder=".form-control-sm"  [(ngModel)]="dateTwo" 
    formControlName="dateTwo">

 <span style="color:red" *ngIf="validation()">DateTwo must be greater than dateone</span>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  [disabled]="!form.valid" >Save changes</button>

</form>
```

This is .ts File :

```
 export class ProjectsComponent implements OnInit {

    dateOne:new Date() ;
    dateTwo:new Date(); 

     ngOnInit() {

    this.doSearch();
    this.dateOne= null;
    this.dateTwo= null;

 this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      dateOne: ['', Validators.required],
      dateTwo: ['', Validators.required],
       selectedPersonId: ['', Validators.required]
    });

}

validation(){
    if(this.dateOne && this.dateTwo){
      if(this.dateOne.getTime() < this.dateTwo.getTime()){
        return false;
      }
      else
        return true;
    }

      }

    }
```

But I'm getting this error :

```
ERROR TypeError: this.dateOne.getTime is not a function
at ProjectsComponent.validation (projects.component.ts:65)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ProjectsComponent.html:89)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14638)
at checkAndUpdateView
```

Comment: Well, in ngOnInit,  you set the dates to null, don't you?

Comment: Yes becaus i don't want that the error message appears even before i  select dateOne and dateTwo , that's why i set the dates to null .

Comment: could you extract the entire problem somewhere we can reproduce it?

Comment: new Date(this.dateOne).getTime() resolved this problem , thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "typeof" this.dateOne and this.dateTwo will be string, you need to convert it to Date() type before using the getTime() function.

```
new Date(this.dateOne).getTime()
```